# Approx_percentile for more decimal place

Tags: sql, presto

is there any way to get approx_percentile to return more than 1 decimal place? Or is there any other similar functions in Presto that is able to provide more than 1 decimal place?

Comment: You can calculate the value using `rank()`/`row_number()` and `count(*)`.  But that might not scale as well.

Comment: Anyway to get it to return more decimal place?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand how the query works, you can use:

```
select <group by columns>,
       min(case when seqnum >= @your_percentage * cnt then x end) as percentile
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by <group by columns> order by x) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by <group by columns>
      from t
     ) t
group by <group by columns>;
```